# C# Can we instantiate Interface with concrete type in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to implement MVVM pattern in `WPF` app. I've used dependency injection to get types inside my viewmodel's constructor like this.

```
private IEntity _newEntity;
private readonly IEntityService _entityService;

public MainViewModel(IEntity entity, IEntityService entityService)
{
    _newEntity = entity;
    _entityService = entityService;
}
```

Now can I do this for whatever reason `_newEntity = new Entity();` or is it anti pattern? In other words can `ViewModel` be coupled with a concrete type?

Comment: Once you switch over to DI, you should use it throughout your project. Mixing DI and local instantiation of complex objects can introduce subtle bugs that are difficult to find. Every time I've done that, it's bitten me at some point.

Comment: Don't use entity tracking or a singleton entity. And resolve an entity instance in a data service rather than viewmodel.

Comment: @Andy you mean i should write a service class in which should have maybe a method that creates and returns 'new WhateverType()' and i can use it in viewmodel ?

Comment: What's the puspose of implementing dependency injection of you still do `_newEntity = new Entity();` in the view model? The whole point of injecting the view model with an `IEntity` is to avoid this.

Comment: @mm8 sir how can i avoid this? this is what confusing me.. I have a ObservableCollection<IEntity> and i just want to add `new Entity{ };` in this collection every time user does something(depending on functionality).. i can't do `new IEntity()`

Comment: If you the view model is responsible for creating entities, then doing `new IEntity()` is perfectly fine. The other option is to inject the view model with a factory that creates the entities on its behalf.

Comment: @mm8 Sir in my case New Object is being created in `ViewModel` A user inputs some data into `TextBoxes` which are binded to `NewData = new Entity()` and when user press `Save` i add this object to a Collection in `ViewModel` (after saving into DB). and finally i rest NewData = new Entity().  Is there anything wrong with my approach?

Comment: Answer: No, it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the view model is responsible for creating entities, then creating these by doing `new Entity()` is perfectly fine.

The other option is to inject the view model with a factory that creates the entities on the behalf of the view model.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to archive.

If you want to call `_newEntity = new Entity();` in `MainViewModels`s constructor like this

```cs
public MainViewModel(IEntityService entityService)
{
    _newEntity = new Entity();
    _entityService = entityService;
}
```

then you're creating a new object of class `Entity` right in the constructor and don't need to pass as an argument to the constructor via dependency injection anymore. But now each `MainViewModel` will have a different instance of `Entity` and probably more importantly you wont have a clean way to access the `Entity` from other ViewModels or Services. If this is what you want to happen, that's fine.

If you want other ViewModels or Services to use the same instance of `Entity` you would register an instance of `Entity` with your DI (dependency injection) container. Most DI-containers offer functionality for that use case, e.g. `containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IEntity>();` in [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/dependency-injection/registering-types.html#registering-singleton-services).

With this out of the way...
If you don't see any future in which you're going to have a need to use classes apart from `Entity` which implement `IEntity` then (in my opinion) there is also no reason to make the code generic for no reason. This follows the [YAGNI (You aren't gonna need it)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle, like don't implement abstractions you probably won't need. In this case you could register the `Entity` as the concrete type instead of the interface like this `containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<Entity>();` and change your `MainViewModel` to

```cs
private Entity _newEntity;
private readonly IEntityService _entityService;

public MainViewModel(Entity entity, IEntityService entityService)
{
    _newEntity = entity;
    _entityService = entityService;
}
```

There's also a nice [video by SingletonSean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQadPrZ7E_A) where he doesn't us Interfaces but concrete classes for the constructor parameters of his ViewModels.

Please note that I just recently got into WPF, so I'm not claiming to be an expert at the time of writing this answer.

Comment: I have a `ObservableCollection<IEntity>` and i just want to add `new Entity();` in this collection every time user does something(depending on functionality).. i got your first point and removed IEntity injection from constructor that was unnecessary.